# How can I force the application to enable Internet access before arriving on the main screen?

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to force every time the app was opened to appear some notification to enable the internet before entering the main screen of the application.

The reason is that the application uses the JSOUP library and when it is not connected when opening the application crashes in the application and does not present the reason for the error that is the Internet's obligation to fetch the information.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Is there not a predictable Exception or even Error that is thrown? Just handle the error. Log it, let the user know what happened then exit (if it's an Error) or offer a means to retry once they've enabled Internet.

Comment: The application quits when you do not have internet access. Can I use try {...} and catch so when the problem occurs a message pops up?

Comment: Most likely. Do you have a stacktrace of the error?

Comment: "The application quits" is not what I meant by the way, that's too vague. When it quits, there should be a an error with stacktrace somewhere. Try running it from the command line and hopefully it spits it out there.

Comment: Sounds like you need better error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where the RuntimeException or Error is thrown from the std_err stacktrace when you run the program from the command line.

Insert a try / catch around a reasonable part of the stacktrace that is your code and then alert the user from there.